What type of web service do GMRT and OpenTopography offer?
From what I understand, GMRT and OpenTopography offer web services for DEMs in geotiff format (raster with unique band of 16 or 32bits) whereas OGC web services serve 3 band rasters.
What's the name of the type of web services GMRT and OpenTopography offer ?

OGC server follow an OGC standard - there is no requirement as to format

yes i'm aware, I'm talking about GMRT and OpenTopography which are not OGC servers !

then you need to provide a link to the services or at least some information about them

sure thing, here is a link for GMRT : http://www.gmrt.org/services/GridServer?west={W}&east={E}&south={S}&north={N}&layer=topo&format=geotiff&resolution=high

the W,E,S,N are just variables to illustrate that you need to fill them with actual coordinates

They tell in https://www.gmrt.org/services/ that it is a "REST type service". GMRT GridServer is a REST-type service for direct access to gridded data from the GMRT Synthesis. Seems to use WADL https://www.w3.org/submissions/wadl/#x3-41000D.1 for defining the service. I think that the short answer is "REST".

OpenTopography's Web services are RESTful services as described here: https://opentopography.org/developers & here: https://portal.opentopography.org/apidocs/#/Public/getGlobalDem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
